# mouse over on list item will target the text of paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my html where i want to target the element id first when clicking on the list element demo similarly targeting the element id second when clicking on the list element demo2 and so on . is it doable by using javascript mouseover function . mouse out function should not display any text . I need my text display only when mouse is hovered on the list item

```
<div class="section-body">
    <div class="slider-details">
        <div class="slider-controls">
            <ul>
                <li id="demo">
                    <strong>test1</strong>
                </li>
                <li id="demo2">
                    <strong>test2</strong>
                </li>
                <li id="demo3">
                    <strong>test3</strong>
                </li>
                <li id="demo4">
                    <strong>test4</strong>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-clip">
            <div class="slider-slides">
                <div class="slider-slide">
                    <h4 class="slider-slide-title">
                        test1
                    </h4>
                    <div class="slider-slide-body">
                        <p id="first">this is para one</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-slide">
                    <h4 class="slider-slide-title">
                        test2
                    </h4>
                    <div class="slider-slide-body">
                        <p id="second">this is para2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-slide">
                    <h4 class="slider-slide-title">
                        test3
                    </h4>
                    <div class="slider-slide-body">
                        <p id="third">this is para3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-slide">
                    <h4 class="slider-slide-title">
                        test4
                    </h4>
                    <div class="slider-slide-body">
                        <p id="fourth">this is para4</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you care to explain more about what you are trying to do?.
When you click on/hover the element with id="demo" or so on what action you are expecting?

Comment: while taing my mouse on id demo paragraph element with id first should populate . on hovering element id demo 2 paragraph element id second should populate . while doing mouse out nothing should happen

Comment: @RaviPrakash what do you mean by populate?

Comment: @TechySharnav I want to display the respective para on mouse over of their corresponding list

Comment: @RaviPrakash So does my answer work for you?

Comment: @TechySharnav no still searching for answer

Comment: @RaviPrakash So what exactly you require from my current answer. I might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can `querySelectorAll` to get all the required `li` and `p` elements. Then you need to iteerate over `li_arr` and add `mouseover` event listener to each `li`. Since their (`li` and `p` elements) numbers are equal, you can directly use the index to target the `p`.
`once: true` will make sure, event listener doesn't fire again, after firing for 1st time. Without any `mouseout`, the changes made to `p` will be retained.

```js
let li_arr = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-controls ul li")

let p_arr = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-slide-body p");

li_arr.forEach((li, index) => {
  li.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    p_arr[index].style.display = "block";  //Add whatever style you want here
  }, {
    once: true
  })
});
```

```css
.slider-slide-body p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-body">
  <div class="slider-details">
    <div class="slider-controls">
      <ul>
        <li id="demo">
          <strong>test1</strong>
        </li>
        <li id="demo2">
          <strong>test2</strong>
        </li>
        <li id="demo3">
          <strong>test3</strong>
        </li>
        <li id="demo4">
          <strong>test4</strong>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-clip">
      <div class="slider-slides">
        <div class="slider-slide">
          <h4 class="slider-slide-title">
            test1
          </h4>
          <div class="slider-slide-body">
            <p id="first">this is para one</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-slide">
          <h4 class="slider-slide-title">
            test2
          </h4>
          <div class="slider-slide-body">
            <p id="second">this is para2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-slide">
          <h4 class="slider-slide-title">
            test3
          </h4>
          <div class="slider-slide-body">
            <p id="third">this is para3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-slide">
          <h4 class="slider-slide-title">
            test4
          </h4>
          <div class="slider-slide-body">
            <p id="fourth">this is para4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added  `data-effects`  to your `li` elements. it has the `id` of the object you wont to effect something.
So getting  this id   you can apply what you wanto to this object.
i used Jquery in this example.

Try this Running the code  and let me know.

```js
$('li').on('mouseover',function(){ 

  // some logs for better understand... 
  //console.log($(this).attr("id")); 
  //console.log($(this).data("effects")); 
  
  //getting the id of the object to effect,  from the html object   where the mouse is    on over 

  eid = $(this).data("effects");  
  
  //do something to object , for example change the color...
  $(eid).css("color","red");
  
  
});


$('li').on('mouseout',function(){ 
  
  eid = $(this).data("effects");  
  
  //do something to object , for example restore the orig color...
  $(eid).css("color","black");
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-body">
    <div class="slider-details">
        <div class="slider-controls">
            <ul>
                <li id="demo" data-effects="#first">
                    <strong>test1</strong>
                </li>
                <li id="demo2" data-effects="#second">
                    <strong>test2</strong>
                </li>
                <li id="demo3" data-effects="#third">
                    <strong>test3</strong>
                </li>
                <li id="demo4" data-effects="#fourth">
                    <strong>test4</strong>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-clip">
            <div class="slider-slides">
                <div class="slider-slide">
                    <h4 class="slider-slide-title">
                        test1
                    </h4>
                    <div class="slider-slide-body">
                        <p id="first">this is para one</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-slide">
                    <h4 class="slider-slide-title">
                        test2
                    </h4>
                    <div class="slider-slide-body">
                        <p id="second">this is para2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-slide">
                    <h4 class="slider-slide-title">
                        test3
                    </h4>
                    <div class="slider-slide-body">
                        <p id="third">this is para3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-slide">
                    <h4 class="slider-slide-title">
                        test4
                    </h4>
                    <div class="slider-slide-body">
                        <p id="fourth">this is para4</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```